# The process cannot access the file 'C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\' because it is being used by another process

Tags: asp.net, iis, asp.net-2.0

I have moved my published asp.net files from

C:/xyz/mywebsite to c:/intepub/wwwroot/mywebsite. In one of the functionality of the website, we are creating a txt file and then editing that text file in the root folder.

When I moved it to new location, I got an error of "cannot create file, premission denied...". Then I right click the intepub folder and allow the access to the group. Now I am able to create a text file in that but unable to write it: The error I am getting is:

```
The process cannot access the file 'C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\' because it is being used by another process.
```

Unfortunately, I can't make changes in the code beacuse it already established website and to deploy it again will take so much time.

Whole functionality was working fine when It was in the folder C:/xyz/mywebsite.

Now what can I do here, without modifying the code?

Comment: Tried restarting IIS?

Comment: Probably because IIS has the file locked. Are you using a file stream? if so make sure you close it.

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure your application properly [closes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.close.aspx) the file after creating it.

If it does, try disabling the [indexing service](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Indexing_Service). It might be indexing the new file right after its creation.